# How to handle data from recieved packets in socketIO-client?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, so maybe my question is rather naive, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet. 
I started socket IO_client and receive packets from the server, which can be seen in the log. But I do not understand at all how it is possible to parse and use data from packages besides a log. Of course, it is possible to parse the log file, but there must be a more correct way. I would appreciate any advice.

```py
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    s = socketIO_client.SocketIO('https://streamer.cryptocompare.com')
    s.emit('SubAdd', {'subs': ['0~Kraken~BTC~USD']})
    s.wait()


except ConnectionError:
    print('The server is down. Try again later.')
```

packets receiving in logs:

```
DEBUG:socketIO-client:streamer.cryptocompare.com:443/socket.io [socket.io packet received] b'2["m","0~Kraken~BTC~USD~2~1561294637.4812~1561294637~0.02637883~10675.8~281.615113314~1561294647~3f"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

It was really easy)
for example, just

```
socketIO.on('m', lambda m: print(m))
```